# Is there any way to obtain content from a form to display in the client (view/template) with JavaScript after submit?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form, a simple form:

```
<form>
    <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstNameInput">
    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
    <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastNameInput">
    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
    <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="emailInput">
    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
    <select class="u-full-width" name="state" id="stateInput">
        <option value="selectstate">State</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
    <input id="submit" class="button-primary submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <span class="success" aria-live="polite"></span>
</form>
```

Essentially I have a eventHandler wired to the form which is listening for the `submit` event.

```
theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    var x = validate(e);
    if (x) {
        formData['firstName'] = firstNameInput.value;
        formData['lastName'] = lastNameInput.value;
        formData['email'] = emailInput.value;
        formData['stateInput'] = stateInput.value;
        console.log('There is now data from the form: :) ');
        for (var prop in formData) {
            console.log(prop + ' : ' + formData[prop]);
        }
    }
}, false);
```

The validate function:

```
function validate(e) {
    var formData = {
            'firstName': null,
            'lastName': null,
            'email': null,
            'stateInput': null
        }
        // Error tracking variable
    var error = false;

    // Do validations
    var emailPattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;


    if ((firstNameInput.value == '') || (firstNameInput.value == null)) {
        firstNameInput.classList.add('invalid-input');
        firstNameInput.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        firstNameInput.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Not valid!';
        error = true;
    }

    if ((lastNameInput.value == '') || (lastNameInput.value == null)) {
        lastNameInput.classList.add('invalid-input');
        lastNameInput.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        lastNameInput.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Not valid!';
        error = true;
    }

    if (!emailPattern.test(emailInput.value)) {
        emailInput.classList.add('invalid-input');
        emailInput.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        emailInput.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Please enter valid email address!';
        error = true;
    }

    if ((stateInput.value == 'selectstate')) {
        stateInput.classList.add('invalid-input');
        stateInput.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        stateInput.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Not valid!';
        error = true;
    }

    // If error, stop the event
    if (error) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('There is no data from the form: ');
        for (var prop in formData) {
            console.log(prop + ' : ' + formData[prop]);
        }
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would think the conditional in the handler would work like this: 
It would only fire if the `x` was true; which it would be if there was a true outcome i.e. the form submitted successfully. the obj, would get filled with the dat and then I would console.log the fields via a `for in loop`

I am having problems understanding why you can't get data from this function?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: See my updated answer for a working version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var formData = {` is contained within your `validate()` function but you are trying to access it from within the anonymous form submit function.

To access it in both places, you either need to pass it as an argument or declare it in a higher scope, outside of both functions like this:

```
var  formData = {
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    email: null,
    stateInput: null
}

function validate(e){

}

theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

});
```

Additionally, right now, your "State" dropdown will always fail validation because you only have one choice and that choice is considered invalid by your validation function.

Your tests for input in the text fields that check for `null` is not going to help you at all because an `input` that contains no data will always return `''`, which you are already testing for, so just that one test is fine, although you may want to change it to test for: `input.value.trim() === ''` because the `trim()` function will remove any leading or trailing spaces in the input.

Finally, when all the form data is valid, you will only see the console report for a brief moment, because the form will submit and cause a redirect to the form's action, so the current page will unload and the console will clear itself out.

Here's the whole thing put together:

```js
var  formData = {
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    email: null,
    stateInput: null
}

var theForm = document.querySelector("form");
var firstNameInput = document.getElementById("firstNameInput");
var lastNameInput = document.getElementById("lastNameInput");
var emailInput = document.getElementById("emailInput");
var stateInput = document.getElementById("stateInput");

theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (validate(e)) {
    formData['firstName'] = firstNameInput.value;
    formData['lastName'] = lastNameInput.value;
    formData['email'] = emailInput.value;
    formData['stateInput'] = stateInput.value;
    logger('There is now data from the form: :) ');
  }
}, false);

function validate(e) {  
  // Error tracking variable
  var error = false;

  // Do validations
  var emailPattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

   if (firstNameInput.value.trim() === '') {
    firstNameInput.classList.add('invalid-input');
    firstNameInput.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
    firstNameInput.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Not valid!';
    error = true;
   }

   if (lastNameInput.value.trim() === '') {
     lastNameInput.classList.add('invalid-input');
     lastNameInput.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
     lastNameInput.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Not valid!';
     error = true;
   }

   if (!emailPattern.test(emailInput.value.trim())) {
     emailInput.classList.add('invalid-input');
     emailInput.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
     emailInput.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Please enter valid email address!';
     error = true;
   }

   if (stateInput.value === 'selectstate') {
     stateInput.classList.add('invalid-input');
     stateInput.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
     stateInput.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Not valid!';
     error = true;
   }

   // If error, stop the event
   if (error) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     logger('There is at least one empty field in the form: ');
     return false;
   } else {
     return true;
   }
}
    
function logger(message){
  console.clear();
  console.log(message);
  for (var prop in formData) {
    console.log(prop + ' : ' + formData[prop]);
    
    // This line will fail here in Stack Overflow, but is correct and
    // will work in a real browser environment. Uncomment it for your use.
    // localStorage.setItem(prop, formData[prop]);
  }
}
```

```css
#spacer { height:100px; }
```

```html
<form>
        <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstNameInput">
        <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
        <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastNameInput">
        <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
        <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="emailInput">
        <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
        <select class="u-full-width" name="state" id="stateInput">
            <option value="selectstate">State</option>
            <option value="someSate">Some State</option>
                        
        </select>
        <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
        <input id="submit" class="button-primary submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <span class="success" aria-live="polite"></span>
    </form>
    
 <div id='spacer'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Scott!!!! Is there any way to capture that object `i.e. form Data?` I tried to wrap the logger in a `setTimeout` but that didn't work...Essentially i'd like to show the data at some point as proof it was submitted...

Comment: Theoretically would I have to save it via `localStorage` in order to truly save it and then display? Only because there is no data base?

Comment: Yes, `localStorage` is a better approach, but realize that it's not infallible (a user can delete their own data, just like they can delete their own cookies). Let me adjust the code for `localStorage`, which is just an additional line to the `logger` function.

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Keep in mind that the Stack Overflow snippet environment doesn't allow access to `localStorage`, so the snippet here will throw an error even though the code is correct and will work in a real browser, so I've commented it here.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. That works—I see the inputs in localStorage, but is there a way to log that out now that it has been saved? I tried an `alert` (for testing) and that didn't work. Would a `setTimeout` be better?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz What do you mean by "log that out now that it has been saved"?

Comment: Well now the form data has been saved in localStorage (after submit) I'am just trying to log it back in the console. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Oh, you mean get the `localStorage` data and report it? Yes, on whatever page you want to see the report, you can extract each item (obviously changing the item name for each) like this: `console.log(localStorage.getItem("firstName"));`

Comment: Ok... I'll explain what I see now...
After submitting I only see the values in `localStorage` when I open a new window and check (dev tools > Application > locaStorage).
So I guess there is NO way to simply display the data in the object after the submit? I guess that's why you need a backend?

Comment: When a form submits, it redirects you to whatever resource is specified. Since that new resource loads up, the old page gets unloaded. Therefore, the code on the first page can't run. However, You can extract the data from localStorage from any page that exists in the same domain as the page that wrote the data. Since you are most likely not using a server for your testing, you don't have a domain, so during testing a second page won't be able to pick up the data.

Comment: So basically because this is on local host, thae logging won't work. Thank you Scott for all your help! I learned a lot!

Comment: localStorage WILL work when requests are made via a server (even local host).

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz You'll have to be more specific about what your setup is (are you requesting the page from a server via http, where is your form redirecting to on submit, where are you trying to extract the localStorage values, etc.).

Comment: Well essentially I am solely working with the validation aspect. The form itself is not being sent anywhere. I was just thinking those values could be displayed in a view with a success message to simulate what would have pre-submitting to the real database/server...

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz I think the issue you are dealing with is that because there is a form, the browser will redirect to the form's destination. That means that that the initial code is no longer going to run. Getting data out of `localStorage` is easy, but you will have to do that on the destination page OR change the `submit` button to a regular button, then show the data and present another button (this time the real `submit` button) that the user can press to confirm their submission.

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz See: https://jsfiddle.net/raLkdpmy/12/ for an updated version of the code that reads out of `localStorage` after writing to it.

Comment: Hey Scott Just wanted to say thanks for your help with all of this. You helped me to understand what was going on and to realize there was something happening locally on my computer which was preventing me from getting that information from localStorage! Cheers friend!

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Glad to be of assistance. Don't forget to up vote my answer and mark it as "the" answer. Good luck!